# Convert list to array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static Array[] getStd()
    {        
      List<student> std = new List<student>();

      string mystr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["str"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mystr);
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student");
      con.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      da.Fill(ds);
      DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];           

      foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
      {
          student st = new student();
          st.name = item["name"].ToString();
          st.address = item["address"].ToString();
          st.sex = item["sex"].ToString();
          st.email = item["email"].ToString();

          std.Add(st);
          student[] arr = std.ToArray();          
      }    
   }
```

I want to convert this list to array and then finally return array.
How do I achieve that?

Or is there other way around to get the same result without using list?

Comment: who would want to deliberately call a method named `getStd` ? ;-) Also just do your `ToArray()` call outside the `foreach` loop and you're done - what have you tried?

Comment: Just `return std.ToArray();`.

Comment: Why are you returning an array-of-arrays? I think you mean to return `Student[]`.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  It seems you know how to convert to an array because you do so here `student[] arr = std.ToArray();`.   Surely you know how to `return` something?  Hard part is already done I would have thought?  Wishing you a good day

Comment: Your code is inefficient, you're unnecessarily loading the entire dataset into memory all at once. Just use a `SqlDataReader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more concise equivalent of your code that runs faster and with considerably less memory:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Student[] GetStudents()
{        
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["str"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [student]";
        con.Open();

        List<Student> ret = new List<Student>();

        using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                ret.Add( new Student() {
                    Name = rdr.GetString("Name"),
                    Address = rdr.GetString("Address"),
                    Sex = rdr.GetString("Sex"),
                    Email = rdr.GetString("Email")
                } );
            }//while
        }//using

        return ret.ToArray();
    }//using 
}//GetStudents
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq, that way will be faster

```
[WebMethod]
public static IEnumerable<student> getStd()
{
            string mystr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["str"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mystr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            var array =dt.AsEnumerable().Select(item =>
                new student
                {
                    name = item["name"].ToString(),
                    address = item["address"].ToString(),
                    sex = item["sex"].ToString(),
                    email = item["email"].ToString()
                }).ToArray();
            return array;
}
```

Also you can return a List

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static List<student> getStd()
 {
            string mystr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["str"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mystr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            var array = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(item =>
                new student
                {
                    name = item["name"].ToString(),
                    address = item["address"].ToString(),
                    sex = item["sex"].ToString(),
                    email = item["email"].ToString()
                }).ToList();
            return array;
    }
```